# Spring oauth2 token store supported by redis

Tags: java, cache, spring, redis

I had to make a demo for Spring oauth2 with redis store for tokens. Started with the sparklr2 (with tonr2) sample app from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/). They are demo apps to show oauth2 powered by spring. Sparklr is the server and tonr is the client. This [link has the details](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples). Wanted to replace, the same JVM, in memory backed token store with one that uses redis. Could have used redis template directly. Decided to use spring cache, so that we can change to MemCache, Eh  or other cache by change in configuration files.

Cloned the project and added a [`CacheTokenStore`](https://github.com/tgkprog/spring-security-oauth/blob/cacheTokenStore/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/impl/CacheTokenStore.java), [`CacheTokenConfig.java`](https://github.com/tgkprog/spring-security-oauth/blob/cacheTokenStore/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/CacheTokenConfig.java) and [properties](https://github.com/tgkprog/spring-security-oauth/blob/cacheTokenStore/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/resources/cache.properties)

Using `SpringCache`, since redis api is more than store/ evict, used the Cache interface to talk to the `Cache` objects.

CacheTokenStore.java  started of as a copy of InMemoryTokenStore. The basic solution and same methods like getTokenCount are there; commented out member variables, replaced with calls to redis.

1. Is this a good approach to use Cache interface?
2. Any other code comments?

```
package org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache;
import org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCachePrefix;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCachePrefix;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.impl.CacheTokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

/**
 * Neev demo. Initializes cache config. Options - see cache.properties.
 * 
 * @author Tushar Kapila. April 2015.
 * */
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/cache.properties")
public class CacheTokenConfig implements InitializingBean {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CacheTokenConfig.class);
    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "_oauth_";

    public static final String[] CACHE_NAMES = new String[] { "accessTokenCache", "authenticationToAccessTokenCache",
            "userNameToAccessTokenCache", "clientIdToAccessTokenCache", "refreshTokenCache", "accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache",
            "refreshTokenAuthenticationCache", "authenticationCache" };

    private @Value("${redis.host-name}") String redisHostName;
    private @Value("${redis.port}") int redisPort;

    /*** Full class name or 1 (default) : in memory, 2 redis */
    private @Value("${cache.use}") String cacheToUse = "1";//TODO constants

    /** 1 InMemory, 2 : cache **/
    private @Value("${store.use}") String storeToUse = "1";

    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName(redisHostName);
        factory.setPort(redisPort);
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    CacheManager createSimpleCacheManager() {
        CacheManager cm = null;
        logger.info("Cache to use :" + cacheToUse);
        if ("2".equals(cacheToUse)) {
            RedisCacheManager rcm = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
            // rcm.setDefaultExpiration(999999);
            boolean usePrefixes = true;
            rcm.setUsePrefix(usePrefixes);
            if (usePrefixes) {
                // seperator
                RedisCachePrefix cachePrefix = new DefaultRedisCachePrefix("-" + OAuth2ServerConfig.SPARKLR_RESOURCE_ID + "-");
                rcm.setCachePrefix(cachePrefix);
                logger.info("Cac ore :" + cachePrefix.prefix(CACHE_NAME));
            }
            //might not need this in spring 4
            for (int i = 0; i < CACHE_NAMES.length; i++) {
                Cache ca = rcm.getCache(CACHE_NAMES[i]);
                logger.info(i + CACHE_NAMES[i] + " " + ca);
            }
            cm = rcm;
        } else if ("1".equals(cacheToUse)) {
            // do below in default
            logger.info("-default below- :");
        } else {
            try {
                cm = (CacheManager) Class.forName(cacheToUse).newInstance();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.info("ERR cacheManager :" + e);
            }
        }
        if (cm == null) {
            SimpleCacheManager scm = new SimpleCacheManager();
            Collection<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < CACHE_NAMES.length; i++) {
                ConcurrentMapCache cmc = new ConcurrentMapCache(CACHE_NAMES[i]);
                caches.add(cmc);
            }
            scm.setCaches(caches);
            cm = scm;
        }
        logger.info("-CacheManager- :" + cm);
        return cm;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        if (tokenStore == null) {
            if ("1".equals(storeToUse)) {
                tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();// std spring
            } else if ("2".equals(storeToUse)) {
                tokenStore = new CacheTokenStore();
            } else {
                try {
                    tokenStore = (TokenStore) Class.forName(storeToUse).newInstance();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    logger.info("ERR :" + e + "cache use :" + cacheToUse + " " + tokenStore);
                }
            }
            logger.info("Token use :" + storeToUse + " " + tokenStore);
        }
        return tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        logger.info("CacheConfig redisHost -:" + redisHostName + ":" + redisPort);

    }
}





package org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.impl;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache.ValueWrapper;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
//import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheConfig;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2RefreshToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthenticationKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

/**
 * Neev demo. Copy of InMemoryTokenStore, with map calls replaced with 
 * calls to cache. Using cache API directly instead of annotations as need to check for nulls etc
 * Can use any backing cache as long as its initialized. 
 * @see CacheTokenConfig
 * 
 * @author Tushar Kapila. April 2015.
 * */
//@CacheConfig(cacheNames = { "accessTokenCache" })//after spring core upgrade
public class CacheTokenStore implements TokenStore, InitializingBean, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CacheTokenStore.class);

    private static final int DEFAULT_FLUSH_INTERVAL = 99000;

    private static final Set<OAuth2AccessToken> OA_TOKEN_EMPTY_LST = Collections.<OAuth2AccessToken> emptySet();

    private Cache accessTokenCache;

    private Cache authenticationToAccessTokenCache;

    private Cache userNameToAccessTokenCache;

    private Cache clientIdToAccessTokenCache;

    private Cache refreshTokenCache;

    private Cache accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache;

    private Cache refreshTokenAuthenticationCache;

    private Cache refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache;

    private Cache authenticationCache;

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2AccessToken> accessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2AccessToken>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2AccessToken> authenticationToAccessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,
    // OAuth2AccessToken>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>> userNameToAccessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,
    // Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>> clientIdToAccessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,
    // Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2RefreshToken> refreshTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2RefreshToken>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> accessTokenToRefreshTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2Authentication> authenticationStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,
    // OAuth2Authentication>();
    //
    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, OAuth2Authentication> refreshTokenAuthenticationStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,
    // OAuth2Authentication>();
    //
    // private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> refreshTokenToAccessTokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    private final DelayQueue<TokenExpiry> expiryQueue = new DelayQueue<TokenExpiry>();//

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, TokenExpiry> expiryMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TokenExpiry>();

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx = null;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager = null;// ctx.getBean("cacheManager", CacheManager.class);

    private int flushInterval = DEFAULT_FLUSH_INTERVAL;

    private AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator = new DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator();

    private AtomicInteger flushCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    static {
    }

    /**
     * The number of tokens to store before flushing expired tokens. Defaults to 1000.
     * 
     * @param flushInterval
     *            the interval to set
     */
    public void setFlushInterval(int flushInterval) {
        this.flushInterval = flushInterval;
    }

    /**
     * The interval (count of token inserts) between flushing expired tokens.
     * 
     * @return the flushInterval the flush interval
     */
    public int getFlushInterval() {
        return flushInterval;
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method for super admin users to remove all tokens (useful for testing, not really in production)
     */
    public void clear() {
        accessTokenCache.clear();
        authenticationToAccessTokenCache.clear();
        clientIdToAccessTokenCache.clear();
        refreshTokenCache.clear();
        accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache.clear();
        authenticationCache.clear();
        refreshTokenAuthenticationCache.clear();
        refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache.clear();
        expiryQueue.clear();
    }

    public void setAuthenticationKeyGenerator(AuthenticationKeyGenerator authenticationKeyGenerator) {
        this.authenticationKeyGenerator = authenticationKeyGenerator;
    }

    public int getAccessTokenCount() {
        // dummy method to pass testing
        // Assert.state(accessTokenCache. || accessTokenStore.size() >= accessTokenToRefreshTokenStore.size(),
        // "Too many refresh tokens");
        // Assert.state(accessTokenStore.size() == authenticationToAccessTokenStore.size(),
        // "Inconsistent token store state");
        // Assert.state(accessTokenStore.size() <= authenticationStore.size(), "Inconsistent authentication store state");
        // return accessTokenStore.size();

        return 100;//Not sure what to do here/ if we need this
    }

    public int getRefreshTokenCount() {
        // dummy method to pass testing
        // Assert.state(refreshTokenStore.size() == refreshTokenToAccessTokenStore.size(),
        // "Inconsistent refresh token store state");
        // return accessTokenStore.size();
        return 100;
    }

    public int getExpiryTokenCount() {
        return expiryQueue.size();
    }

    public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        String key = authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication);
        ValueWrapper vw = authenticationToAccessTokenCache.get(key);
        if (vw == null){
            return null;
        }
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = (OAuth2AccessToken) vw.get();
        if (accessToken != null && !key.equals(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(readAuthentication(accessToken.getValue())))) {
            // Keep the stores consistent (maybe the same user is represented by this authentication but the details
            // have changed)
            storeAccessToken(accessToken, authentication);
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        return readAuthentication(token.getValue());
    }

    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthentication(String token) {
        ValueWrapper vw = this.authenticationCache.get(token);
        if (vw == null){
            return null;
        }
        return (OAuth2Authentication) vw.get();
    }

    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken token) {
        return readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(token.getValue());
    }

    public OAuth2Authentication readAuthenticationForRefreshToken(String token) {
        ValueWrapper vw = this.refreshTokenAuthenticationCache.get(token);
        if (vw == null){
            return null;
        }
        return (OAuth2Authentication) vw.get();
    }

    public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        if (this.flushCounter.incrementAndGet() >= this.flushInterval) {
            flush();
            this.flushCounter.set(0);
        }
        logger.info("storeAccessToken token "+ token + ", " + authentication);
        this.accessTokenCache.put(token.getValue(), token);
        this.authenticationCache.put(token.getValue(), authentication);
        this.authenticationToAccessTokenCache.put(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication), token);
        if (!authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            addToCollection(this.userNameToAccessTokenCache, getApprovalKey(authentication), token);
        }
        addToCollection(this.clientIdToAccessTokenCache, authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(), token);
        if (token.getExpiration() != null) {
            TokenExpiry expiry = new TokenExpiry(token.getValue(), token.getExpiration());
            // Remove existing expiry for this token if present
            expiryQueue.remove(expiryMap.put(token.getValue(), expiry));
            this.expiryQueue.put(expiry);
        }
        if (token.getRefreshToken() != null && token.getRefreshToken().getValue() != null) {
            this.refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache.put(token.getRefreshToken().getValue(), token.getValue());
            this.accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache.put(token.getValue(), token.getRefreshToken().getValue());
        }
    }

    private String getApprovalKey(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        String userName = authentication.getUserAuthentication() == null ? "" : authentication.getUserAuthentication().getName();
        return getApprovalKey(authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(), userName);
    }

    private String getApprovalKey(String clientId, String userName) {
        return clientId + (userName == null ? "" : ":" + userName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void addToCollection(Cache cache, String key, OAuth2AccessToken token) {
        ValueWrapper vw = cache.get(key);
        if (vw == null) {
            synchronized (cache) {
                vw = cache.get(key);
                if (vw == null) {
                    cache.put(key, new HashSet<OAuth2AccessToken>());
                }
            }
        }
        vw = cache.get(key);
        if(vw!= null){
            Object o = vw.get();
            ((HashSet<OAuth2AccessToken>) o).add(token);
        }else{
            logger.info("no hashset, key " + key + " token " + token + ", "  + (token == null? token : token.getValue()));
        }
    }

    // private void addToCollection(ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>> store, String key, OAuth2AccessToken token) {
    // if (!store.containsKey(key)) {
    // synchronized (store) {
    // if (!store.containsKey(key)) {
    // store.put(key, new HashSet<OAuth2AccessToken>());
    // }
    // }
    // }
    // store.get(key).add(token);
    // }

    public void removeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken) {
        removeAccessToken(accessToken.getValue());
    }

    public OAuth2AccessToken readAccessToken(String tokenValue) {
        return (OAuth2AccessToken) this.accessTokenCache.get(tokenValue).get();
    }

    public void removeAccessToken(String tokenValue) {
        logger.info("removeAccessToken tokenValue " + tokenValue);
        ValueWrapper vw = this.accessTokenCache.get(tokenValue);
        OAuth2AccessToken removed = null;
        if (vw != null) {
            removed = (OAuth2AccessToken) vw.get();
        }
        logger.info("removeAccessToken removed " + removed);
        this.accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache.evict(tokenValue);
        // Don't remove the refresh token - it's up to the caller to do that
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = null;
        vw = this.authenticationCache.get(tokenValue);
        if (vw != null) {
            authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) vw.get();
        }
        this.authenticationCache.evict(tokenValue);
        if (authentication != null) {
            this.authenticationToAccessTokenCache.evict(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication));
            Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens;
            tokens = (Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>) this.userNameToAccessTokenCache.get(authentication.getName()).get();
            if (tokens != null) {
                tokens.remove(removed);
            }
            String clientId = authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId();
            tokens = null;//
            vw = this.clientIdToAccessTokenCache.get(clientId);
            if (vw != null) {
                tokens = (Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>) vw.get();
                if (tokens != null) {
                    tokens.remove(removed);
                }
            }

            this.authenticationToAccessTokenCache.evict(authenticationKeyGenerator.extractKey(authentication));
        }
        logger.info("end removeAccessToken.");
    }

    public void storeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        this.refreshTokenCache.put(refreshToken.getValue(), refreshToken);
        this.refreshTokenAuthenticationCache.put(refreshToken.getValue(), authentication);
    }

    public OAuth2RefreshToken readRefreshToken(String tokenValue) {
        OAuth2RefreshToken token = null;
        ValueWrapper o = this.refreshTokenCache.get(tokenValue);
        if (o != null) {
            token = (OAuth2RefreshToken) o.get();
        }
        return token;
    }

    public void removeRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken) {
        removeRefreshToken(refreshToken.getValue());
    }

    public void removeRefreshToken(String tokenValue) {
        this.refreshTokenCache.evict(tokenValue);
        this.refreshTokenAuthenticationCache.evict(tokenValue);
        this.refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache.evict(tokenValue);
    }

    public void removeAccessTokenUsingRefreshToken(OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken) {
        removeAccessTokenUsingRefreshToken(refreshToken.getValue());
    }

    private void removeAccessTokenUsingRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        ValueWrapper vw = this.refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache.get(refreshToken);
        if (vw != null) {
            this.refreshTokenToAccessTokenCache.evict(refreshToken);
            String accessToken = (String) vw.get();
            if (accessToken != null) {
                removeAccessToken(accessToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientIdAndUserName(String clientId, String userName) {
        ValueWrapper vw = userNameToAccessTokenCache.get(getApprovalKey(clientId, userName));
        if (vw == null) {
            return OA_TOKEN_EMPTY_LST;
        }
        logger.info("findTokensByClientIdAndUserName userName:" + userName + ", " + vw.get());
        Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> result = (Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>) vw.get();
        return result != null ? Collections.<OAuth2AccessToken> unmodifiableCollection(result) : OA_TOKEN_EMPTY_LST;
    }

    public Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> findTokensByClientId(String clientId) {
        ValueWrapper vw = clientIdToAccessTokenCache.get(clientId);
        if (vw == null) {
            return OA_TOKEN_EMPTY_LST;
        }
        logger.info("findTokensByClientId clientId " + clientId + ", " + vw.get());
        Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> result = (Collection<OAuth2AccessToken>) vw.get();
        return result != null ? Collections.<OAuth2AccessToken> unmodifiableCollection(result) : OA_TOKEN_EMPTY_LST;
    }

    private void flush() {
        TokenExpiry expiry = expiryQueue.poll();
        while (expiry != null) {
            removeAccessToken(expiry.getValue());
            expiry = expiryQueue.poll();
        }
    }

    private static class TokenExpiry implements Delayed {

        private final long expiry;

        private final String value;

        public TokenExpiry(String value, Date date) {
            this.value = value;
            this.expiry = date.getTime();
        }

        public int compareTo(Delayed other) {
            if (this == other) {
                return 0;
            }
            long diff = getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) - other.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            return (diff == 0 ? 0 : ((diff < 0) ? -1 : 1));
        }

        public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
            return expiry - System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        try {
            logger.info("CacheStore afterPropertiesSet :" + cacheManager);
            accessTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("accessTokenCache");
            authenticationToAccessTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("authenticationToAccessTokenCache");

            userNameToAccessTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("userNameToAccessTokenCache");

            clientIdToAccessTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("clientIdToAccessTokenCache");

            refreshTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("refreshTokenCache");

            accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache = cacheManager.getCache("accessTokenToRefreshTokenCache");

            refreshTokenAuthenticationCache = cacheManager.getCache("refreshTokenAuthenticationCache");

            authenticationCache = cacheManager.getCache("authenticationCache");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd HH mm ss");
            String s = "b" + sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
            logger.info("authenticationCache " + authenticationCache);
            logger.info("a s -:" + s);
            logger.info("a s " + s);
            authenticationCache.put("a", s);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            logger.info("ERR " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        return cacheManager;
    }

    public void setCacheManager(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        logger.info("get4cacheManager :" + cacheManager + ".");
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    //test method TODO remove.
    @Cacheable(value="authenticationCache")
    public String getAVal1(String m) {
        logger.info("getAVal1 :" + m + ".");
        return m + "-1";
    }

}
//TODO unit tests
```

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I don't know squat about sparklr2, tonr2, and very little about oauth and Redis. I do have a couple of admittedly superficial remarks though.

#### Hardcoded 1 and 2 values

Why hardcode 1 and 2 to select between in-memory or cache as the store?
The numbers alone are meaningless,
and you could easily replace them with constants,
or put both into an `enum`.

#### Use the enhanced for-each loop when possible

Instead of this:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < CACHE_NAMES.length; i++) {
>     ConcurrentMapCache cmc = new ConcurrentMapCache(CACHE_NAMES[i]);
>     caches.add(cmc);
> }
> ```

Use an enhanced for-each loop:

```
for (String name : CACHE_NAMES) {
    ConcurrentMapCache cmc = new ConcurrentMapCache(name);
    caches.add(cmc);
}
```

#### `Long.compare`

You can simplify this:

> ```
> return (diff == 0 ? 0 : ((diff < 0) ? -1 : 1));
> ```

Using `Long.compare`:

```
return Long.compare(diff, 0);
```

#### Other minor things

This is a bit unusual way to place annotations:

> ```
>     private @Value("${redis.host-name}") String redisHostName;
> ```

I'm used to this form instead:

```
    @Value("${redis.host-name}")
    private String redisHostName;
```

Comment: thanks but really want to know answer about my firs question. agee ith you other points. appreciate it